# SPRING include in my project

Tags: spring

I'm doing a java project without xml. How I can translate the

```
<el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
```

line of the XML file ?

I tried to create a class that looks like this, but do not know who or what to call:

```
package com.journaldev.configWeb;

import javax.el.ELContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.access.el.SpringBeanELResolver;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.jsf.FacesContextUtils;


public class SpringBeanFacesELResolver extends SpringBeanELResolver {
        @Override
    protected BeanFactory getBeanFactory(ELContext elContext) {
        return getWebApplicationContext(elContext);
    }


    protected WebApplicationContext getWebApplicationContext(ELContext elContext) {
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        return FacesContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(facesContext);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please change your title and make it describe your problem, specifically.

Comment: And please make your tags more explicit to. **neither** PrimeFaces **nor** Java is a correct tag.

Comment: my problem is I want to add my project SPRING, but does not have xml files. I've found that if you create a class like that shown works, but I do not file is the need to call or as